# Laravel admin form image control source

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

In Laravel-admin image control source path is incorrect.
I upload the image to S3 and delete the local image file after that.
But when loading the form, image control is seeking the image in local/media folder.
The reason is  `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/media'` set like this.

```
'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
                'url' => env('APP_URL').'/media',
                'visibility' => 'public',
```

I cannot change the `url`, instead of that somehow I wanna set it here when loading.

```
$form->image('thumb_path', 'Thumbnail');
```

Two of below issues are related to this.

https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin/issues/5118

https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin/issues/4220

Anybody found a workaround for this or faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

What version of laravel are you using in your app

Comment: Version is 4.0.5